# Treat 2nd column with space as one column

Tags: bash, awk, sed, sh, ksh

I have a command that has an output of the sample below.

```
SAN_FR_9644T "Threat for Security" /vol/SAN44_39/SAN_FR_9644T-PPIE/Threat for Security
SAN_FR_3131T ZZ$        /vol/SAN44_39/SAN_FR_3131T-PPEL
SAN_FR_2281T "Control Line" /vol/SAN44_39/SAN_FR_2281T-PPF/33YShared/Control Line
SAN_FR_0021T "TT  FPI Station and Source" /vol/SAN145_22/SAN_FR_0021T-PPCR/TT  FPI Station and Source
SAN_FR_3131T DEFF_DEV /vol/SAN22_57/SAN_FR_3131T-PPAG/DEFF_DEV
SAN_FR_2241D BIX_E$    /vol/SAN99_45/SAN_FR_2241D-PPA/E
SAN_FR_2241D NULL_F$    /vol/SAN99_45/SAN_FR_2241D-PPA/F
SAN_FR_2241D TRIP   /vol/SAN99_45/SAN_FR_2241D-PPA/I
SAN_FR_2241D FINANCE   /vol/SAN99_45/SAN_FR_2241D-PPA/G
```

As you can see, there are rows on the 2nd column that has a space in it but there is a double quote (").

tried running this command but it only works for rows without spaces.

```
command | awk '{print $2}'
```

output:

```
"Threat
ZZ$    
"Control
"TT  
DEFF_DE
BIX_E$ 
NULL_F$
TRIP   
FINANCE
```

what is wanted to get is the complete list of the 2nd column even if there's a space on it.

```
Threat for Security
ZZ$
Control Line
TT  FPI Station and Source
DEFF_DEV
BIX_E$
NULL_F$
TRIP
FINANCE
```

would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, with any `awk`, please try following. Simple explanation would be, using `match` function matching regex `"[^"]*"` to match from 1st occurrence of `"` to next occurrence of `"` and printing matched sub-string and `next` will skip all further statements. In case this condition is NOT TRUE then anyways usual way of printing 2nd field will work so printing $2 then.

```
awk 'match($0,/"[^"]*"/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);next} {print $2}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With GNU `awk`, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -v FPAT='[^ ]*|"[^"]+"' '{gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$2);print $2}' Input_file
```

Comment: very helpful as always. thank you :) @RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` you can look at the lines without a quote first, and next the lines with quotes.
That would give the ugly command:

```
sed -r '/^[^"]*$/s/[^ ]* ([^ ]*).*/\1/; s/[^"]*"([^"]*).*/\1/' inputfile
```

The two parts can be combined, but in this attempt you need to remove quotes at the end:

```
sed -r 's/[^ ]* (["][^"]*|[^ ]*).*/\1/; s/"//' inputfile
```

This can be done smarter (without the fix `s/"//` for removing the `"`)

```
sed -r 's/[^ ]* ("([^"]*)|([^ ]*)).*/\2\3/' inputfile
```

Explanation of the last `sed`:

- `'s/[^ ]*` 
  Remove first word (everything without a space and the next space).
- `((...)|(...)).*/\2\3/`
  Look for 2 different matches (OR), which result will end up in `\2` OR `\3`.
  Using `\2\3` will show the matched string.
  `.*` will remove the rest of the line.
- `"([^"]*)`
  A field starting with a `"`, but keep the quote outside the remembered string.
  The string will continue until the next quote.
- `([^ ]*)`
  String without spaces.